# Elasticsearch Query DSL Filter Including Middle Occurrences

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

I am facing an issue with Elastisearch Query DSL while using a prefix filter for the "log_message" field.
The goal is to display logs where the "log_message" field has a prefix of "Started". However, the filter is also includes lines where "Started" appears in the middle of the message, not just at the beginning.
Here's my query:

```
{
  "prefix": {
    "log_message": "started"
  }
}
```

- Here's my log message:
  2023-11-20 10:49:34.445 | INFO | [restartedMain] --- 14348 | o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext | | Started xxxxxxxxxxx.

Her's my logstash Pattern:

%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} |%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:log_level}%{SPACE}|%{SPACE}[%{DATA:thread}]%{SPACE}---%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:process_id}%{SPACE}|%{SPACE}%{DATA:class}%{SPACE}| |%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log_message}(\r|\n)?

i try to restart elastisearch ang logstash but the problem is still present

Comment: Could you please provide same document from index and index mapping ?